# Can my domain name get more expensive?

Tags: domain-name, godaddy

This may sound like a strange question but I am wondering if I buy a domain name for, let's say, 10$ for 1 year and during that year it becomes very popular attracting lots of visitors.

At the end of 1 year when I need to re-register, is it possible that it becomes more expensive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is possible your registrar could raise prices on your domain, they typically do not. However, if it does expire it can then be resold at whatever price they decide.

You may want to look at the registrars terms to see if they offer any 'lock-in' guarantee that the price won't change or anything like that. Support would also be able to get you in touch with someone who can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: If they did decide to raise the price, and you found a better offer with a different registrar, you could transfer it, right?